# Maven multi-module deploy forking

Tags: maven, deployment

I've been having an issue with deploying a multi-module project using maven where certain modules need to be skipped and I need the deploy to happen after all of the modules have been built.

For further information I'm using Maven version 3.3.3 and version 2.8.2 of the Maven deploy plugin.

I attempt to deploy the modules using `mvn clean deploy -U -DdeployAtEnd=true` via Jenkins.

Example POMs of what my modules look like:

### Parent

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>child-A</module>
        <module>child-B</module>
        <module>child-C</module>
        <module>child-D</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

### Child A

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.parent</artifactId>
        <version>com.parent</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child-A</artifactId>

    <modules>
        <module>grandChild-A/<module>
        <module>grandChild-B/<module>
        <module>grandChild-C/<module>
        <module>grandChild-D/<module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

### Child B-D

Child B has one sub-module (grandchild E) but C and D do not.

### Grandchildren

None of these have submodules.

### Maven deploy Plugin

Example of how the deploy plugin is defined:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    <executions>
</project>
```

This plugin is used in every module but skip configuration is merged in for children B-D and grandchild E.

When the deployAtEnd option is used the deploy plugin puts each reactor project into a list after it is successfully built and if it doesn't have the skip configuration set. Then it deploys all of the modules at the end.

The plugin uses a counter `READYPROJECTSCOUNTER` which is initialised as a `private static final AtomicInteger` to determine when all of the projects have been built.

However when I try to deploy my project two iterations of the counter are created. One which increments for the parent and children and the other which increments for the grandchildren.

Therefore when it checks the counter against the size of project list only one of the counters is checked and because the counter hasn't reached the project list size the deploy process isn't kicked off.

Has anyone else run into anything similar to this or, if not, would anyone be able to explain why the counter is initialised twice (i.e. why the process forks into two separate instances)?

Comment: First: Why are there modules which needed to be skipped? Why are you trying to deploy your project in two iterations? And what does `One which increments for the parent and children and the other which increments for the grandchildren.` mean? Are you talking about the versions in this case?

Comment: Really? Does not make sense...about what size are we talking about?

Comment: 1. I'm skipping certain modules to save space in our Nexus repo.
2. I'm not trying to deploy the project in two iterations. It's just what seems to happen.
3. What I meant by that sentence was I logged out the value of the counter and what I saw was the counter incrementing normally for grandchildren A-D (which are built first) but when the next module (child A) was built the counter went back down to 1. The following module (grandchild E) saw the counter go up to 5 but then as the remaining children and the parent was built the counter dropped back down to 2 and then incremented to 5.

Comment: The artifacts for the whole project take up about 50MB. This is not too bad on its own but my company has a lot of components and we have space issues on our repository.

Comment: How are you skipping modules? How have you printed out the counter ? Furthermore you didn't answer my question: About what size are we talking about...really about 50 MB? It is not worth the time...Sorry to say but increase the size of the nexus repository...(what is the current size overall?)...

Comment: Sorry...how are you skipping modules by adding ? Can you give an concrete example..best would be to make an example project on github to show what you are doing?

Comment: I'm skipping modules by adding:
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
to the execution in children B-D and grandchild E.
Additionally increasing the size of our repository won't fix the issue of the build forking into two separate iterations.

Comment: As i mentioned before please make a sample project where you can show how you are going...What are two separate iterations (can you explain what you mean by that?)

Comment: Iteration may be the wrong word. I think the process is being run in two separate threads but I'm not sure how to check that. Also I haven't specified that Maven should use parallel builds so I'm not sure why it would be doing that.

Comment: Which process runs in two separate thread? Maven usually starts only in a single thread...except you use things like `-T 2` on command line? Do you have a log output of a Maven run?

Comment: That's what I'm unsure about. I haven't used any `-T` options on the command line but the deploy process seems to be running in two separate threads. One for the grandchildren and the other for the children and parent. I mean, I might be wrong about the multithreading but I can't think of any other reason why a `private static final` variable would be initialised twice.

Comment: maven-deploy-plugin does not fork anything...Do you call Maven from root of your multi module build ? Do you use plugins which define their own life cylcle (extensions?) ? Have you checked the log file if there is a `-T ...` defined ? Are you running your build from command line or with a CI solution like Jenkins ?

Comment: Yep, I call Maven from the root. I've checked the logs and there is no `-T` option defined. I've also tried running the build from both the command line and Jenkins with the same issue on both. However, we do use the maven-mixin-plugin which does have the <extensions> value set to true. Is that what could be causing it?

Comment: Yes exactly. Every plugin which defines it's own lifecycle can cause problems with deployAtEnd..At the moment i'm trying to improve maven-deploy-plugin to get it independent from that.